# How the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is calculated

Tags: javascript, binary

I'm wondering how the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is calculated from the representation in IEEE754. JavaScript uses double precision 64bit float numbers, and I assume that under this system the biggest number is all 1's in exponent and mantissa, which is:

[image]

```
1.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 2^{1024} = 
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 2^{972}
```

I tried to convert

```
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 * 2^{972}
```

into decimal, but haven't arrived at the number `9007199254740991`.

Comment: I believe it's (2^53)-1 - because `binary floating-point number has a coefficient of 53 bits` according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: Start here: [MDN: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (links to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for details on the number format)

Comment: by the way, the "internal" representation of MAX_SAFE_INTEGER is `0 10000110011 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks for your comments. Why is exponent `10000110011`? If we make it all 1's we can store bigger integer, no?

Comment: perhaps ... but can all integers be represented between this proposed max, and the actual one ... MAX_SAFE_INTEGER isn't the maximum integer, it's the integer that is the maximum that below which **all** other integers can be exactly expressed ... above this value, there are "gaps"

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks, an example of the `gaps` would greatly help

Comment: Math.pow(2, 53) = 9007199254740992 ... add one, what do you get in javascript? ... or simply do `9007199254740992+1` in the console ... P.S. I would think that would make 9007199254740992 the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER (seeing as it is exactly 1 greater than 9007199254740991) ... but, there must be some reason why it isn't

Comment: I get the same number :). Will try to figure out why it is so. Thanks